# `drawCircle()` radius parameters units?

Tags: android, android-canvas

What is the unit for the radius parameter in the `Canvas.drawCircle()` method?

is it pixels? or dip?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle(float, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)

I tried to look at the source to to see if I could get any idea, but the method is just a wrapper, and the documentation does not specify anything.

Comment: Thank you @FrankN.Stein . Could you point to the source of the documentation please? So that from next time instead of asking, I can search the documentation on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As reported in the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html):

`When you're writing an application in which you would like to perform specialized drawing and/or control the animation of graphics, you should do so by drawing through a Canvas. A Canvas works for you as a pretense, or interface, to the actual surface upon which your graphics will be drawn — it holds all of your "draw" calls. Via the Canvas, your drawing is actually performed upon an underlying Bitmap, which is placed into the window.`

A Bitmap, by definition, uses **pixels**, and nothing else, as its unit.

Therefore, All the `drawXYZ()` methods are in **px**.